# Time Tracker in Android Independent of the System time

Tags: android, datetime

I've tried to google around but I still can't find the best answer.

All I want is very simple, I am new to Android and I am developing a Game which will give some daily Bonuses to the user, if he plays Everyday.
My Code is:

```
date = new Date();
    dateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    dateString = dateFormate.format(date);
        if(!sharedPreferences.getString("date").equals(dateString))
    {
            sharedPreferences.putString("date", dateString).commit();
            ... Here I give Bonus to user
        }
```

BUT the Problem is, This code is dependent on the System Date. User can Easily change the date and can get its daily Reward.
I want to track 24 hours time once he starts playing The game.
Can Anyone Help me Please.
This would be much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has internet access you could get time from your own server, rather than user time.

You could listen to `Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` and sync with server time only if you have recieved this intent.  You wont be syncing with server unless user changes time manually.

Answer (score 0):

instead of comparing that date has changed you can check if

- date is bigger than previos one: asssign bonus and remeber date
- date is smaller than previos one: user is cheating-remove all bonuses and do not update old date

this solution is of course not bullet proof but more secure than you previos one

Comment: But issue would be same.
User can update the date to next day, every time after getting reward.
It would return me bigger value....

Comment: that#s true but as soon as you set the date back (which is necesary to use calendar and alarmclock) you will loose the bonus.